# Marketing Cloud - Does API call executed inside a Cloud Page count toward account limit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, cloudpage

Considering a limit of 6M API Call per year for a corporate license,
I wonder whether an external API call which is called from a Cloud Page count toward this limit.

Please anyone can help?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any external call out limits in Marketing Cloud?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292144/are-there-any-external-call-out-limits-in-marketing-cloud), https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205898/marketing-cloud-api-limits

Comment: thanks rachid, I saw those questions and I am not very sure that it fits with my answer. I am not asking when a Marketing cloud api is called (transactional send journey) neither when a Data Extension is called. I was asking when from a Cloud page I do call an external API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 6M limit you mentioned is for calling the Marketing Cloud APIs (regardless if you’re calling them from external resources or internally from Marketing Cloud). This limit is not related in any way to calling external APIs from Marketing Cloud.

The limit of calls for the external service you’re working with will be determined by that external service, not by Marketing Cloud.